# ReactJS Swiping Cards

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

Forked and following this tut:
https://github.com/alexandre-garrec/react-swipe-card/tree/master/src

But how did he get his actions? Also I want to refactor this for ES6 but I don't get what's in `import { storiesOf, action } from '@kadira/storybook';` please help.

The tutorial looks simple as follows:

```
import Cards, { Card } from 'react-swipe-card'


const data = ['Alexandre', 'Thomas', 'Lucien']

const Wrapper = () => {
  return (
      <Cards onEnd={action('end')} className='master-root'>
        {data.map(item => 
          <Card 
            onSwipeLeft={action('swipe left')} 
            onSwipeRight={action('swipe right')}>
            <h2>{item}</h2>
          </Card>
        )}
      </Cards>
  )
}
```

But some things are unanswered like: `={action('end')}` - What are these `actions`? It appears they come from here: `react-swipe-card/.storybook/config.js` - but this file itself references: `require('../stories/index.js');` and in index.js https://github.com/alexandre-garrec/react-swipe-card/blob/master/stories/index.js it again refrences: `import { storiesOf, action } from '@kadira/storybook';` ...so slightly confusing. Can anyone make this work with ES6? I think I just need to know how to make `action` work or create a similar action with similar functionality.

Comment: thats https://github.com/storybooks/storybook - a tool to dev and showcase your react components and their API

Comment: Thanks so do I need action? I am testing in browser. In the root example here https://github.com/alexandre-garrec/react-swipe-card the 'action' isn't even referenced.

Comment: I've made an update to my OP.

Comment: I could be wrong but maybe this is targeting mobile devices. I went with http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs instead as did the job I needed.